# Add an image to the banner of a schema: Intranet Migrated Content?

Tags: image

[image]I cannot get the image to save when I try to add it the top of the page in the banner section. The image will appear but when I go to save the page it says saving but never says it was successful. Is there some other part of the block I need to fill out in order to get it to work??

I added the image of the screen I am seeing. I took this a little over a minute after I hit the same button, as you can see the "save" and "save and close" buttons are not faded out like they normally fade when you save something. The drop down list just says "saving item" like its doing something but really isn't.

Comment: Could you please update which browser are you using for CMS. If this not IE then try all steps in IE as well.

Comment: I'm using chrome and I'm also using the sdl editior

Comment: Or tridion, I never know what to call this thing. I'm an intern here and I'm trying to learn as much as I can

Comment: The CMS is called SDL Tridion. The two UIs are the folder-based Content Manager Explorer, which is sometimes called "Tridion" to contrast it with Experience Manager, which shows your staging, non-live site.

Comment: There are a few ways of adding images to content or pages and most start with creating or uploading a Multimedia Component to store the image. You then use the Multimedia Component from a rich text field by inserting an image, in a Component as a link, or directly on a Page in the Component Presentation tab. It'll help describing which scenario you're working on. It's also probably good to show a colleague or IT your steps to confirm which part isn't working.

Comment: The UI should prevent saving but also warn you if you're missing any mandatory fields. If you use save or save & close, even without a confirmation the next step is usually to publish the change from the CME or to press Finish Editing in Experience Manager to see your changes on the site.

Comment: I'm gonna do some work on it today and get images and other details about what's going on so I can give you all a better idea of the issue.

Comment: I added some info to the original question @AlvinReyes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from @Nickoli's suggestion for database maintenance, there is also a hotfix available for Chrome 49 upwards with Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 available [HERE](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1_HR1/index.aspx) (CME_2013.1.1.1673 - login required). A server administrator would only be able to perform this hotfix.

If you are able to save and close using Internet explorer, I would suggest using that until your Tridion system or server administrator provides a fix.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I actually downloaded firefox and it helped with the whole saving issue. Overall it helped the system run better so I'm gonna proceed with that and see how it goes. THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad it helped! It would help your colleagues, if you update your system administrator with the hotfix. If your question is answered, can you accept the answer so that the community can keep up q/a ratio as well?

Comment: I will mention the hotfix to my mentor and see what he says. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

"Top of the page in the Banner section" seems to be a custom implementation detail, not a generic Tridion feature. However the issue of not being able to save the page looks like an issue. Look at the Event Viewer log on the Content Manager server. There should be an error stack trace to help narrow down on the root cause. Share it here and we can tell more.

Generically speaking, this kind of an issue is due to the CM database needing some maintenance to make it go faster, i.e. running statistics and making sure it has enough swap memory.

Comment: Its appearing to be a little difficult to take a picture of the drop down with the error tracer. Basically it just sits there saying its saving the page but does nothing. I've let it sit for quite some time too and it hasn't helped. What is the idea behind the swap memory??

Comment: That would be maintenance on the Content Manager's database rather than a task for end users. Nick is answering from a CMS or system administrator perspective. It looks like you'll best get help internally by contacting your IT, manager, or the development team. You could mention Nick's answer, but most likely IT will check the Event Viewer and system logs to troubleshoot.